# Using Oauth2 AccessToken of a particular user in gdata for retrieving picasa photos

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gdata, gdata-api, picasa

I have implemented python code for authentication user for picasa web albums referring this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2WebServerFlow)! and I have recieved the user credentials for particular user.

Now I want to use this access token to fetch a user's Picasa Web albums. But I am using gdata python library for it. Gdata has its own authentication process but I wish to use the credentials retrieved from above process.

Is there a way to use this access_token explicitly and fetch Photos using gdata??

The reference doc for gdata is [this](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#upgrading-to-a-session-token)!

Answer (score 0):

Worked around
Simply use like this:
gd_client =  gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer TOKEN HERE'})